# regex checking for match doesn't work

Tags: jquery, regex

Here is the code in jQuery:

```
    //Verify license number is only numbers
    $('lic_num').keyup(function() {
        var valid_lic_num = '/[0-9-]{3,20}/';
        var raw_text =  $(this).val();
        $('#status').html(raw_text);
        if (valid_lic_num.match(raw_text)) {
            $('#status').html('Password regex okay');
        } else {
            $('#status').html('License number regex failed');
        }
    });
```

The goal is when the user enters any character other than 0 through 9 or a hyphen, it change the content of #status to display whether the regex passed. Not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're doing it in reverse.  You want `raw_text.match(valid_lic_num)`.  Additionally, you want `valid_lic_num` to be a regex, not a string.

Comment: try `if (valid_lic_num.test(raw_text))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex definition from this:

```
var valid_lic_num = '/[0-9-]{3,20}/';
```

to this:

```
var valid_lic_num = /[0-9-]{3,20}/;
```

When you put quotes around it, the JS interpreter makes it a string, not a regex.

Also, `.match()` is a string method, not a regex method.  You can use `.test()` instead like this:

```
//Verify license number is only numbers
$('lic_num').keyup(function() {
    var valid_lic_num = /[0-9-]{3,20}/;
    var raw_text =  $(this).val();
    $('#status').html(raw_text);
    if (valid_lic_num.test(raw_text)) {
        $('#status').html('Password regex okay');
    } else {
        $('#status').html('License number regex failed');
    }
});
```

Comment: That was it. New to regex, and had tried test first and, obviously, it failed because of the quotes, but I did not realize that.